# How to insert a dashed line over a bigwedge symbol so that the dashed line behaves like overline would?

Tags: spacing, macros, symbols

I want to insert a dashed line over symbols \bigwedge and \bigvee in such a way that it looks exactly like a solid line over the same symbols. I know how to insert a solid line over those symbols (for example, \overline{\bigwedge}). Since I asked a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117293/how-to-create-dashed-right-arrow-over-symbol) a few years ago about how to add a dashed arrow over a letter, I tried to use the code from there. Resulting code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{amsart}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz} %for dash

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\preclosure}[1]{%
  \vbox {\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
  \preclosurefill \crcr
  \noalign{\kern-\p@\nointerlineskip}
  $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}

%% fill with (short) minus signs
\def\preclosurefill{%
  $\m@th%
  \xleaders\hbox{$\mkern0mu\shortbar\mkern0mu$}\hfill%
  \shortbar%
$}

%% make the minus shorter to fit \dashedleftarrow
\def\shortbar{%
  \smash{\scalebox{0.4}[1.0]{$-$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In order to distinguish between lattice operations $\bigvee, \bigwedge$ in structure A, we use the following symbols: $\overline{\bigvee}, \overline{\bigwedge}$. Similarly, to distinguish between operations $\bigvee, \bigwedge$ in structure B, we use the following symbols: $\preclosure{\bigvee}, \preclosure{\bigwedge}$.

Inline: $\overline{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}$, $\preclosure{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}$.

In separate line:
\[
\overline{\bigvee_{\alpha \in I}}, \preclosure{\bigvee_{\alpha \in I}}.
\]
\end{document}
```

Resulting document:

[image: Resulting document]

I have the following problems:

1. Somehow in inline mode the $\preclosure{\bigwedge}$ symbol is made bigger than just $\bigwedge$.
2. The dashed line does not allocate vertical space and runs into text
3. It seems to me that when $\overline{\bigvee}$ is inline, then the overline is too close to the V symbol, making it look almost like triangle. If I zoom in, then I can see that it is not so, but at 100% zoom it looks too close. How to move the overline a bit higher? Or do You think that this is not a problem?

It is not necessary to use exactly the same code I wrote, I just used what I already had, but not successfully :)

Comment: As for #1, your `\preclosure` macro has `\displaystyle` in it.  That is how it ends up bigger.

Comment: Hm, I tried to remove the \displaystyle{#1} and replace it with #1, which resulted in the symbol \bigvee being small inline AND in math mode, which is not desirable.

Comment: Well now you have the opposite problem. The dollar signs put it into inline mode! So you could use `\mathchoice` or find a way to not use a specific math mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd avoid `\overline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dashover}[2][\mathop]{#1{\mathpalette\df@over{{\dashfill}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\fillover}[2][\mathop]{#1{\mathpalette\df@over{{\solidfill}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\df@over}[2]{\df@@over#1#2}
\newcommand\df@@over[3]{%
  \vbox{
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{##\cr
      #2{#1}\cr
      \noalign{\kern1pt}
      $\m@th#1#3$\cr
    }
  }%
}
\newcommand{\dashfill}[1]{%
  \kern-.5pt
  \xleaders\hbox{\kern.5pt\vrule height.4pt width \dash@width{#1}\kern.5pt}\hfill
  \kern-.5pt
}
\newcommand{\dash@width}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    2pt
  \else
    \ifx#1\textstyle
      1.5pt
    \else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle
        1.25pt
      \else
        \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle
          1pt
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\solidfill}[1]{\leaders\hrule\hfill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text:
$\bigvee_{\alpha\in I}$,
$\fillover{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}$,
$\dashover{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}$.

Subscript:
$\scriptstyle\bigvee_{\alpha\in I}$,
$\scriptstyle\fillover{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}$,
$\scriptstyle\dashover{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}$.

Display:
\[
\bigvee_{\alpha \in I}
\fillover{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}
\dashover{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You probably want to define

```
\newcommand{\fbigvee}{\fillover{\bigvee}}
```

\newcommand{\dbigvee}{\dashover{\bigvee}}

The commands `\fillover` and `\dashover` have an optional argument that sets the type of the object. Default is `\mathop`, but it can be `\mathrel` or `\mathbin`, so you could use

```
\newcommand{\dvee}{\dashover[\mathbin]{\vee}}
```

and `$x\dvee y$` would produce

[image]

You may want to adjust the separation space, the argument to `\noalign` in the code for `\df@@over`. However, the macro is not optimized for usages other than `\mathop`, something more should be done in the case of other types.

Comment: Thank You for Your detailed reply. I currently only need the \mathop variant, but thank You for including the possibility for \mathrel and \mathbin variants. I adjusted the separataion space to 2pt and it looks very good. Plus, I like how the dashed and solid lines come from the same code, so I can be sure that they behave similarly. Super!

Answer (score 2):

This may have the drawback of slightly affecting line spacing, but...

I substitute `\Overline` which does an `\overline` with a little extra stack gap added.

And for `\preclosure`, I modified it so that it preserves the math style of the argument, using the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` construct of the `scalerel` package.

I did not really address the issue of not enough gap between the `\preclosure` and the line above it.  I would suggest either using smaller wedges (if that is permitted), or going to larger line spacing.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,draft]{amsart}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz} %for dash
\def\Overline#1{\ThisStyle{\overline{\addstackgap[.4pt]{\SavedStyle#1}}}}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\preclosure}[1]{%
  \ThisStyle{%
  \vbox {\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
  \preclosurefill \crcr
  \noalign{\kern-\p@\nointerlineskip}
  $\hfil\SavedStyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr}}}}

%% fill with (short) minus signs
\def\preclosurefill{%
  $\m@th%
  \xleaders\hbox{$\mkern0mu\shortbar\mkern0mu$}\hfill%
  \shortbar%
$}

%% make the minus shorter to fit \dashedleftarrow
\def\shortbar{%
  \smash{\scalebox{0.4}[1.0]{$-$}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In order to distinguish between lattice operations $\bigvee, \bigwedge$ in structure A, we use the following symbols: $\Overline{\bigvee}, \Overline{\bigwedge}$. Similarly, to distinguish between operations $\bigvee, \bigwedge$ in structure B, we use the following symbols: $\preclosure{\bigvee}, \preclosure{\bigwedge}$.

Inline: $\Overline{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}$, $\preclosure{\bigvee}_{\alpha \in I}$.

In separate line:
\[
\Overline{\bigvee_{\alpha \in I}}, \preclosure{\bigvee_{\alpha \in I}}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You both for Your effort. Both suggestions are very good; however, egreg's answer has a bit better spacing, so I chose that at the moment.