# How to create an arrow above a dashed arrow (the easiest way)?

Tags: arrows, mathjax

I'd like to know how to make two arrows: one above another where the lower arrow is the dashed one.

I came up with a code like this:

```
$$
    f_n \overset{\rightarrow}\dashrightarrow f
$$
```

which evaluates to:

[image]

And I would like it to look like this:

[image]

There is a [thread where it was discussed how to print arrows like these above a letter (linked)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117293/how-to-create-dashed-right-arrow-over-symbol), but the solution was quite long.

I believe there must be an easier way to do it.

Notes:

- I use the [Atom editor](https://atom.io/)
- with a package called [markdown-preview-plus](https://github.com/Galadirith/markdown-preview-plus)
- the package uses **MathJax**.
- I do not have to provide a preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **MathJax**, the following might be useful, `\substack` puts the symbols over each other, `\textstyle` enlarges the font, `\mathrel` fixes the horizontal spacing:

```
f_n\mathrel{\substack{\textstyle\rightarrow\\\textstyle\dashrightarrow}} f
```

Result image from [MathJax Live Demo](https://www.mathjax.org/#modal-livedemo):

> [image: Result MathJax]

But it would look quite ugly in **LaTeX**:

> [image: Result LaTeX]

- `\longrightarrow` would be better, but the then the arrow would be a little bit too large.
- The arrow heads are quite different. And they are different from `\rightrightarrows`.
- Depending on the other arrows in your document, it might be wise to redraw all arrows in TikZ or other drawing package to get a consistent
  appearance of the arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this with tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\[ f_n\; \tikz{\draw[dashed, ->] (0,0) -- ++(0.35cm, 0);\draw[->] (0,0.125cm) -- ++(0.35cm,0);}\; f \]

\end{document}
```

Or make it a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\stackedarrow}{\ensuremath{\;}\tikz{\draw[dashed, ->] (0,0) -- ++(0.35cm, 0);\draw[->] (0,0.125cm) -- ++(0.35cm,0);}\ensuremath{\;}}

\begin{document}
\[ f_n \stackedarrow f \]

\end{document}
```

Either way will look identical, like this: [image: stackedarrow]

I know this doesn't satisfy the "easier way to do it", but it works!