# Standard AMS-Sum Operator using MnSymbols?

Tags: pdftex, amsmath, math-operators, mnsymbol

Because a professor who reads one of the lectures I attend this term writes so slowly, I typeset a lecture script for that lecture in TeX. For the use of some symbols and for better underbrace rendering I use MnSymbol. As those of you who are familiar with MnSymbol may know, it offers a different sum operator than the amsmath-package. It also offers a different integral operator, but I already fixed that by loading "esint" as last math font package, as I like those amsmath math operators better.
Is there a way of easily "fixing" the sum operators to be the standard ones without having to stop using MnSymbol? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a small set of symbols from MnSymbols to use, it is relatively easy to do. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes thats the case, its mainly \(big)cup dot and the braces from MnSymbol. What does the trick then in this case? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: this question may help if you want to use just a few symbols from "another" font: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: Ok, so I'll have to find out how the syntax is for importing the sum operator from amsmath. I'll try this by myself, if I don't succeed I'd be glad if one of you could help me.

Comment: I did not find sny table whatsoever which showed me the name of the \sum operator in amsmath, I do not know how to achieve this by myself. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

See FOLLOW UP below for importing CM symbols into MnSymbol.  But first...

Import MnSymbols:

If you only use a few `MnSymbol`s, it is easiest to import just those, rather than loading `MnSymbol` package.  Here is how it is done (I used, for `MnSymbol` specific reference, [Dashed left arrow over symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114501/dashed-left-arrow-over-symbol), though other questions on this site about importing symbols are also useful).

It helps to look through the MnSymbol package document (or better still, `mnsymbol.sty`) to find from which font family the symbol derives, and then it helps to use `\fonttable` (package `fonttable`) to display the font family in a table, from which you can determine the slot number corresponding to the desired glyph.

First, to determine font families, I look through `mnsymbol.sty` for the glyph name, and use it to determine the font family:

[image]

[image]

From the above pictures, I see that the `\bigcupdot` glyphs (`\displaystyle` and`\textstyle`) are `\mathop`s and come from the `symbols` font.  The name `symbols` is associated with `MnSymbolF` font family.  These are needed in my MWE.  The `\cupdot` glyph comes from a different font family (`MnSymbolC`).

In the MWE below, I show the importation of 3 glyphs from two different font families: `\cupdot`, `\tbigcupdot` (textstyle `\bigcupdot`) and `\dbigcupdot` (displaystyle `\bigcupdot`).  I then use `\mathchoice`, to tell LaTeX to use the proper bigcupdot style in the appropriate math style.

If you uncomment my commented lines concerning `fonttable`, you can see the font tables from which I determined the glyph's slot numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
% =============================================
%Import symbols from font MnSymbol without importing the whole package
% =============================================
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC} {U} {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\cupdot}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{60}
% =============================================
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolF5
  <6-7> MnSymbolF6
  <7-8> MnSymbolF7
  <8-9> MnSymbolF8
  <9-10> MnSymbolF9
  <10-12> MnSymbolF10
  <12-> MnSymbolF12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolF-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolF-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolF-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolF-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolF-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolF-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolF-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{SymbolF} {U} {MnSymbolF}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\dbigcupdot}{\mathop}{SymbolF}{35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tbigcupdot}{\mathop}{SymbolF}{34}
\def\bigcupdot{\mathchoice{\dbigcupdot}{\tbigcupdot}{\tbigcupdot}{\tbigcupdot}}
% =============================================
%\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\centering
$ x \cupdot y$\par
$ x \bigcupdot y \quad \scriptstyle x \bigcupdot y
 \quad \scriptscriptstyle x \bigcupdot y$
\[ x \bigcupdot y\]
%\clearpage\fonttable{MnSymbolF8}
%\clearpage\fonttable{MnSymbolC10}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

FOLLOW UP:

The OP asked if MnSymbol can be the default, with (for example), `\sum` being imported from default LaTeX.  As barbara points out in the comment, the default `\sum` comes from the cmex font set.  Here, I import it as `\Xsum` (I am not sure if my `\DeclareFontShape` invocation is appropriate for cm fonts, but I mimicked what had been done for MnSymbol):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mnsymbol}
% =============================================
%Import symbols from font cmex without importing the whole package
% =============================================
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {cmex}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{cmex}{m}{n}{
  <-6> cmex5
  <6-7> cmex6
  <7-8> cmex7
  <8-9> cmex8
  <9-10> cmex9
  <10-12> cmex10
  <12-> cmex12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{Xcmex} {U} {cmex}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xdsum}{\mathop}{Xcmex}{88}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xtsum}{\mathop}{Xcmex}{80}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Xsum}{\mathchoice{\Xdsum}{\Xtsum}{\Xtsum}{\Xtsum}}
% =============================================
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\centering
sum under MnSymbol:\par
$\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i $
\[\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i \]
Defined Xsum from cmex:\par
$\Xsum_{i=1}^2 x_i $
\[\Xsum_{i=1}^2 x_i \]
\tiny\fonttable{cmex8}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, the disjunct union symbol is not quite the deal, its the bracket rendering, still its a very kind answer; I'll just try this with the sum operator out of the ams math package.

Comment: @Friedrich I wasn't sure what you had in mind when you mentioned "brackets" (the `\{\}` brace glyphs actually looked very similar to computer modern defaults), so I did not try to do anything with that.  But the framework is here for importing glyphs from `MnSymbol`.

Comment: Could you help me with importing from amsmath anyways or does this method not work with this?

Comment: @Friedrich  In general, each font has a similar, though unique, method.  But in this case, I believe the `\sum` operator you make mention of does not actually originate from the `amsmath` font set, as the loading (or not) of `amsmath` does not change the look of the `\sum`.  Thus, I'm guessing you are actually seeking the `\sum` glyphs from the LaTeX-default Computer-Modern font set (which are discarded with the loading of `MnSymbol`).  Is this the case?

Comment: @Friedrich -- `\sum` is "basic tex".  the definition for these symbols (in the font `cmex`) is found in the file `fontmath.ltx`.

Comment: @Friedrich Please see `FOLLOW UP`.