# \mathbb and MnSymbol

Tags: luatex, mathspec, mnsymbol

I am experimenting a little with fonts and I'd like to use the following `MWE` to write some math:

```
\documentclass[%
paper=a4,%
fontsize=12bp,%
parskip=half-,%
notitlepage,%
oneside,%
reqno,%
numbers=noenddot,%
listof=totoc,%
bibliography=totoc,%
index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\sffamily\bfseries\boldmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[MnSymbol,quiet]{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro} 
\setmainfont[       Ligatures               = {Common,TeX},
                    Numbers                 = {Lowercase, Proportional}, 
                    SmallCapsFeatures       = {Letters     = SmallCaps,
                    Numbers                 = Lowercase,
                    Kerning                 = Uppercase,
                    LetterSpace = 5}]{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}

\title{Something}
\author{Someone}
\maketitle

blah blah blah and $\mathbb{N}$
\end{document}
```

However, this produces an error since I haven't included `\amsfonts` or `\amssymb`
which are incompatible with `MnSymbol`. Any ideas how to overcome this? I am not hung up on using `MnSymbol`, so if some other math font specification works well with `MinionPro`, then I'd like to hear your suggestions.

P.S. I am compiling with `lua`.

Comment: Do you need all on `MnSymbol` or just a glyph or two?  Importing individual glyphs from it, while leaving all else intact, as in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217986/standard-ams-sum-operator-using-mnsymbols/219282#219282

Comment: What do you want `\mathbb` to produce? That is, since you are using Minion etc., do you even want this to use the AMS fonts?

Comment: The copy of `MinionPro.sty` which I have defines `\mathbb`. So either use `MinionPro` or take the relevant definitions from it, if that works better with your remaining setup. EDIT: Or, better, use the facilities provided by `mathspec` to set this up.

Comment: No, I don't care about AMS fonts. What is the equivalent to get a blackboard N with MnSymbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the `\mathbb` math alphabet:

```
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=12bp,
  parskip=half-,
  notitlepage,
  oneside,
  reqno,
  numbers=noenddot,
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  index=totoc
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[margin=1in,noheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[MnSymbol,quiet]{mathspec}

\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro} 
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures = {Common,TeX},
  Numbers = {Lowercase, Proportional}, 
  SmallCapsFeatures = {
    Letters = SmallCaps,
    Numbers = Lowercase,
    Kerning = Uppercase,
    LetterSpace = 5
  }
]{Minion Pro}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\sffamily\bfseries\boldmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\title{Something}
\author{Someone}
\maketitle

blah blah blah and $\mathbb{N}$
\end{document}
```

[image]