# Different Sum signs

Tags: math-mode

During my research I noticed different sum signs:

[image]

The first one is mine and is created by `$\sum_{i=1}^n$`. The second one is from a paper. Any idea how to write it in LaTeX?

Comment: The left one is from a document with `\usepackage{mathptmx}` (or similar Times-like font), the right one is with the standard font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapting my answer here, [Standard AMS-Sum Operator using MnSymbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217986/standard-ams-sum-operator-using-mnsymbols/219282#219282), for `mathptmx`, you can use either font's sum operator (`\sum` mathptmx and `\Xsum` computer modern), while retaining the underlying `mathptmx` math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx,mathtools}
% =============================================
%Import symbols from font cmex without importing the whole package
% =============================================
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {cmex}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{cmex}{m}{n}{
  <-6> cmex5
  <6-7> cmex6
  <7-8> cmex7
  <8-9> cmex8
  <9-10> cmex9
  <10-12> cmex10
  <12-> cmex12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{Xcmex} {U} {cmex}{m}{n}

%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xdsum}{\mathop}{Xcmex}{88}% LaTeX can find displaystyle
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xsum}{\mathop}{Xcmex}{80}
% =============================================
%\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\centering
sum under mathptmx:\par
$\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i $
\[\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i \]
Defined Xsum from cmex:\par
$\Xsum_{i=1}^2 x_i $
\[\Xsum_{i=1}^2 x_i \]
%\tiny\fonttable{cmex8}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one uncomments the two lines in the MWE related to `fonttable`, one will see the computer-modern math extension font table, showing the text and displaystyle sum signs at slots 80 and 88, which are reflected in my `\DeclareMathSymbol` declarations.

Comment: `\mathchoice` isn’t actually necessary: see below.

Comment: @GuM Long time to reply, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

I’m making this an answer because it doesn’t fit in a comment: the `\mathchoice` machinery is unnecessary, because the functionality it is aimed to is already built into TeX at “machine level”.  See *The TeXbook*, Appendix G, Rule 13 (the sentence that spans the last two lines on page 443).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
% \usepackage{mathtools} % unrelated to the problem, but...
\usepackage{amsfonts} % ... apparently this line is superfluous if the 
                      % "mathtools" package is loaded.

% No need to re-declare the cmex fonts under a different encoding:
%
% \DeclareFontFamily{U} {cmex}{}
% 
% \DeclareFontShape{U}{cmex}{m}{n}{
%      <-7.5> cmex7
%   <7.5-8.5> cmex8
%   <8.5-9.5> cmex9
%   <9.5->    cmex10
% }{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{Xlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xsum}{\mathop}{Xlargesymbols}{80}



\begin{document}

Sum under \texttt{mathptmx}: \( \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i \).
Now displayed:\[\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i \]

Defined \verb|\Xsum| from \texttt{cmex}: \( \Xsum_{i=1}^2 x_i \).
Now displayed:\[\Xsum_{i=1}^2 x_i \]

\footnotesize

Repeat in \verb|\footnotesize|.

Sum under \texttt{mathptmx}: \( \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i \).
Now displayed:\[\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i \]

Defined \verb|\Xsum| from \texttt{cmex}: \( \Xsum_{i=1}^2 x_i \).
Now displayed:\[\Xsum_{i=1}^2 x_i \]

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: I don't think that `cmex5`, `cmex6` and `cmex12` exist.

Comment: @egreg: Indeed, they don’t.  I must have absent-mindedly copied Steven’s code.