# Using the basic \approx symbol with MnSymbol

Tags: mnsymbol

I want to use MnSymbol (to get various sorts of down arrows), but I don't like its \approx symbol. I'd like to use the basic one instead. I've tried using savesym (as below), but this still outputs the mnsymbol version. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{approx}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\restoresymbol{approx}{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\approx$

\end{document}
```

**Edit -- Additional Question**

@Steven B. Segletes's answer works perfectly for the problem as I asked it. But, I've found that there are a bunch of other symbols that I'd like to prevent MnSymbol from changing around. So, I wonder if there might be a solution coming from the other direction: can we prevent MnSymbol from introducing any new definitions except for the specific symbols we want to add? (The ones I specifically want are \ndownarrow, \ndasheddownarrow, and \dasheddownarrow.)

...I now see that @Steven B. Segletes has answered this already ([Standard AMS-Sum Operator using MnSymbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217986/standard-ams-sum-operator-using-mnsymbols/219282#219282)). But like I said in a comment below, I'm a total layman and get scared looking at all this font changing stuff. So if anyone has a solution of a different sort, that would be helpful.

Comment: if you want to use just selected symbols from a particular font, this might help: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**REVISION** (at GuM's suggestion)

GuM, who clearly knows more about LaTeX font usage than I, improves my answer immensely, by tying into the encoding of `cmsy` already known to LaTeX (`OMS`) and thus avoids the need to declare a new font family and shape.  GuM further calls out the right incantation to provide bold support, as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,bm}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Xsymbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{Xsymbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xapprox}{\mathrel}{Xsymbols}{25}

\begin{document}
$a\Xapprox b \bm{\Xapprox} c$

$a \approx b \bm{\approx} c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here, I declare the CM symbol font (`cmsy`, see The TeXbook, p. 431) as a new font family with `\DeclareFontFamily`.  Then, with `\DeclareFontShape`, I tell which glyph sizes to use, based on the desired point size (e.g., any thing bigger than 12 points is a scaled version of the `cmsy12` glyphs).  I then declare a new symbol font `Xcmsy` that uses the `cmsy` font family.  Finally, I employ `\DeclareMathSymbol` to extract the right glyph from the `Xcmsy` symbol font and call it `\Xapprox` .  I make sure sure it is employed as a `\mathrel` type, and it uses slot `25` (`'031` octal, `"19` hex) of that Symbol font, which corresponds to the `\approx` symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {cmsy}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{cmsy}{m}{n}{
  <-6> cmsy5
  <6-7> cmsy6
  <7-8> cmsy7
  <8-9> cmsy8
  <9-10> cmsy9
  <10-12> cmsy10
  <12-> cmsy12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{Xcmsy} {U} {cmsy}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xapprox}{\mathrel}{Xcmsy}{25}
\begin{document}
$a\Xapprox b$

$a \approx b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works! For total laymen like me, would you be able to summarize what this solution is doing?

Comment: @SamZukoff See edited answer.  I hope this helps.  Even I have to look it up to refresh my memory of the syntax.

Comment: 1. Why not just `\DeclareSymbolFont{Xcmsy}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}`, and let that the size functions defined in `omscmsy.fd` (which are pretty different from yours) be used?  2. Why not to add support for the `bold` math version by adding `\SetSymbolFont{Xcmsy}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}` (`omscmsy.fd` does define a suitable font shape)?

Comment: I took the liberty to reorganize slightly your code for the sake of logical order.  Good answer, anyway! :-)

Answer (score 4):

There's no way for saving `\approx` with `savesym`. *No symbol* defined with `\DeclareMathSymbol` can.

The `savesym` package can *only* work with commands defined with `\newcommand` (provided the command has no optional argument); it won't do if the command is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` for reasons described in the documentation of `letltxmacro` (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47372/4427).

Let’s see what happens. If you use the correct syntax, that is

```
\usepackage{savesym}

\show\approx

\savesymbol{approx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\restoresymbol{mn}{approx}

\show\approx
\show\mnapprox
```

(the `\show` lines are just for debugging) you will get, on the terminal,

```
> \approx=\mathchar"3219.

> \approx=\mathchar"3219.

> \mnapprox=\mathchar"3704.
```

Instead of `mn` you might use any string you like better (for commands that work with `savesym`, of course, not this one).

This means that `\approx` is a relation symbol (`3`), from the font in math group `2`, slot `"19`.

However, when the document starts, `MnSymbol` assigns `\U/MnSymbolF/m/n/10` to the font in math group `2`, which corresponds to `MnSymbolF10`. The relevant part of the font table is shown here:

[image]

and indeed, your document will print

[image]

which isn't very much like an `approx` symbol. Indeed in `MnSymbol.sty` we find

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}
```

which overrides the standard declaration for the `symbols` font, corresponding to math group 2. The assignments of `operators` to math group 0, `letters` to math group 1, `symbols` to math group 2 and `largesymbols` to math group 3 are mandatory. Later on, the 25th line (25 decimal is `19` hexadecimal) after line 1446 (where a counter is reinitialized to zero for defining the symbols from the `symbols` font) has

```
\Decl@Mn@Char\dbigdoublecurlywedge{symbols}{\mathop}
```

which confirms the “unexpected” symbol you see instead of `\approx`. It must be said that `MnSymbol` uses very obscure code. Indeed, as shown by the value of `\mnapprox`, the “approximates” symbol in `MnSymbol` is from the font in math group 7, slot `"04`.

The only way to go is with a `\DeclareSymbolFont` strategy as described in Steven’s fine answer.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

I read the commands of savesymbol and restore symbol.

When you save the "approx" then the "origapprox is created"

When you restore "approx" by the command:

```
\restore{last}{approx}
```

then the "approx" has to become again the same as "origapprox" that have been saved and "lastapprox" will become the last value of approx before restoring.

So if we have the next code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{approx}


\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\restoresymbol{UnwantedChanged}{approx}


\begin{document}

$\approx$


$\origapprox$


$\UnwantedChangedapprox$
\end{document}
```

we are expecting an approx with the symbol of MnSymbol
an origapprox with the symbol before load of MnSymbol and a UnwantedChangedapprox
with MnSymbol loaded

but the code above gives the real approx symbol only in the last row.

By removing the last line of printing and the restore command, I saw that 
the savesymbol command had already restored the symbol and was printing 
as approx the old approx and as origapprox the last one...

This means that to solve your problem you has to just remove the restore commant... I don't know why... may be the code in savesym has been changed
and restores automatically after loading a new symbol or may be MnSymbol does this trick

**Old Answer: (to understand the first -fair- comment of @StevenB.Segletes)**

You wrote the command with opposite arguments. Try:

```
\restoresymbol{approx}{amssymb}
```

Comment: This succeeded in printing an approx symbol, but it's the mnsymbol one.

Comment: Your suggestion uses improper syntax for `\restoresymbol`, and thus not only does not solve the problem, but can mislead readers.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks... I reading the "documentation" of savesymbol to find how it works

Comment: Good point. I'll fix the post.