# Is there a font where lower-case $x$ and $z$ look more like $X$ and $Z$, and how do I switch all my equations to have that font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I like $X$ and $Z$ more than $x$ and $z$. The lower case versions are too fancy (too many curves, whereas the $X$ and $X$ have lines that are more "straight"). Is there a font where the lower case $x$ and $z$ are just smaller versions of the straight-line containing $X$ and $Z$? How do I change my LaTeX preamble so that all math mode occurrences of $x$ and $z$ use that font, but the rest of the alphabet remains the same?

For example, \mathrm{x} and \mathrm{z} look fine to me. Is there a way to make all occurrences of x and z in math-mode, to look like \mathrm{x} and \mathrm{z}, while allowing the rest of the alphabet to be unaffected?

Comment: Is MathJax not working?

Comment: `\usepackage{pxfonts}` may be an improvement.  However, maybe you are looking for a sans serif math font.  Also try `\usepackage{eulervm}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: What if I only want the x and z to be non-Italics in mathmode, but the rest of the letters I don't want to make any changes to?

Comment: Search the site for "import" and "font".  Answers will follow the lines of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217986/standard-ams-sum-operator-using-mnsymbols

Comment: ...though I would add that it is generally not visually compatible to mix letters of different fonts in the same context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default fonts are defined in `fontmath.ltx`.

The relevant lines for `x` and `z` are:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`z}
```

So `x` and `z` will be set in `cmmi`. We could instead use the slanted variant of `cmr` just for these characters:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersslanted}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sl}
\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{lettersslanted}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{lettersslanted}{`z}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersslanted}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{sl}
\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{lettersslanted}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{lettersslanted}{`z}
\begin{document}
$xyz$

$XYZ$
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: What a beautiful (and simple!) solution. I have accepted the answer! How did you know about this easy solution?

Comment: @user1271772, I didn't actually. But I figured that it must be possible because there are packages that change the maths font. I looked through the style file of one of these to see how it was done. Then used `grep` to search through my TeX tree to find the defaults and modified to suit.

Comment: I would not have known to even start where you started, so thank you so much!!!